# Find all printers in a network or at least the printers IP

Tags: windows, networking, batch, printer, network-printer

I am currently working on a project which gets information from a printer via `snmp protocol` (Name, printed Pages, Toner levels...).

It is currently working when I have a printer IP Address, but I have to apply this in a very large company (means a huge network) and I need something that I can find all Printers in the Network.

This should run on a Windows based system in a batch script.

I know that i can find all IP's of the network with `arp -a` or that it is possible to search trough out all IP's to find a printer.

But I have a subnetmask of `255.0.0.0` which means there are 16 million (16581375) IP's which I have to search which is very resource intense and time consuming.

In Windows control panel there is a option `add network or wireless printer` where a list of all network printers is shared.

I cannot find any information how they get this list or any type of source code.

[image]

Does anyone know how windows get this list ?

Or is there a better way to get a list of all Network Printers rather than bruteforcing the whole network for printers?

And when bruteforcing is the only solution I need a better way to check if the IP belongs to a printer because sending an `snmp` command to any IP is not the best way.

Comment: HP's WebJetAdmin and Xerox's CentreWareWeb will find all printers. Both are free downloads

Comment: A large company is likely to have multiple vlans (though that subnet mask may indicate otherwise). You're gonna have a _tough_ time discovering anything across vlan boundarys.

Answer (score 1):

As of Windows Vista, I believe you should use
Web Services Dynamic Discovery (WS-Discovery).
You will probably need to write a program for it.

From Wikipedia [WS-Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery):

> Web Services Dynamic Discovery (WS-Discovery) is a technical
>   specification that defines a multicast discovery protocol to locate
>   services on a local network. It operates over TCP and UDP port 3702
>   and uses IP multicast address 239.255.255.250. As the name suggests,
>   the actual communication between nodes is done using web services
>   standards, notably SOAP-over-UDP.

Microsoft supplies the discovery library : A .NET class library that implements the WS-Discovery protocol ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298707.aspx)).

You can also find an example C++ program at
[Web service discovery (WS-Discovery) sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WS-Discovery-SDK-Sample-8138b0d1), described as:

> This sample shows how to use the Web Service Discovery API to perform WS-Discovery routines by using the IWSDiscoveryProvider, IWSDiscoveryProviderNotify, IWSDiscoveryPublisher and IWSDiscoveryPublisherNotify interfaces.

Some references that I found :

- [Web Services Dynamic Discovery (WS-Discovery) Version 1.1](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/discovery/1.1/os/wsdd-discovery-1.1-spec-os.html)
- [Web Services Dynamic Discovery (WS-Discovery)](http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/ws-discovery.pdf)

Comment: No guarantee any printers would respond to discovery requests.